# Как бороться с непостоянными ошибками в Beautifuloup AttributeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, beautiful-soup, bs4

Ищу элемент при парсинге `A = soup.find('div', class_='aaa')`, но периодически возникает ошибка:

```
    A = soup.find('div', class_='aaa')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

то отрабатывает нормально, то появляется такое, подскажите как можно исправить или добавить проверку, потому что try-except не помогают тут

Comment: if not soup: continue

Comment: или проверяйте, что есть response.content,  или response.status_code не 403, а 200, например